# Disable highlight button in uitableviewcell when select row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have custom UITableViewCell and two buttons inside. When I  select row, background for buttons change for the same color as background of selected row, and border for buttons  disappears.

How Can I disable change border/background color for button when row is selected  ?

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this using a clear background view for my cells and disabling selection color of the row, but I needed it that way. Don't know if it suits your need, but you can try this:

```
UIView *selectedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
selectedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Hope this helps.

Do checkout this thread as well : [Why do all backgrounds disappear on UITableViewCell select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053340/why-do-all-backgrounds-disappear-on-uitableviewcell-select)

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a UIView and assign the desired background color.
2) Render the UIView to an UIImage
3) Set the backgroundImage of the button for the desired state.

```
UIView *colorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
colorView.backgroundColor = color;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(colorView.bounds.size);
[colorView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[button setBackgroundImage:colorImage forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
```