# Button in (static) cell disappears when clicking on the cell itself instead of the button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, cell

i'm having a weird issue with the code on my (static) cells. In multiple cells I have a UIButton. When I click on it, it's all fine, but when I click on the area next to the button (still in the cell itself) it turns grey (color when selected cell) + the button also disappears!

I tried to change the background of the cell to white when pressed with the following code:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let myBackView=UIView(frame:cell.frame)
    myBackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView

}
```

but the issue is still there.[image: When the cell itself isn't pressed]
This is when the static cell isn't pushed 
[image: When I pressed the cell (not the button)]
This is when I pressed the cell (NOT the button within the cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue when selecting UITableViewCells, see [Why do all backgrounds disappear on UITableViewCell select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053340/why-do-all-backgrounds-disappear-on-uitableviewcell-select)

If you don't intend the cell to be selected, implement [this delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:):

```
- (NSIndexPath * _Nullable)tableView:(UITableView * _Nonnull)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath * _Nonnull)indexPath
```

and return `nil` when `indexPath` is the one of your cell. This will disable selection for this cell.

If none of your cells is intended to be selected, it's even easier, just set your [UITableView's `allowsSelection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/allowsSelection) to `NO` (this can also be done in Interface Builder).

Comment: Hi, I do need some cells to be selected though. I tried the "willSelectRowAtIndexPath", but it didn't solve my problem (can't select the cells that need to work, and the buttons still disappear). Is it because I'm using 7 static cells?

Comment: Did you look at the first link I posted? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053340/why-do-all-backgrounds-disappear-on-uitableviewcell-select) I don't think the buttons disappear, their background become transparent and as your image and text are white you don't see anything anymore.

Comment: Hey, found a solution that worked for me: I link the static cell via IB to the code, and then just do `mailCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None` This kept my button working, but the cell didn't do the whole disappear act.

Comment: IIRC you can also set the `selectionStyle` in Interface Builder.

Comment: Yes Indeed, but for some reason I prefer to have it in code as well :D but thanks for the help, it made me look in the right direction