# Strange behaviour of Subclassed UITableViewCell when selected

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a subclass of UITableViewCell, which has a number of UILabels, a UIImageView and a UIView in it.

I have the cell set to highlight blue when it is selected. The strange behaviour that I am observing is the UIView that I have added as a property of the UITableViewCell subclass disappears when the cell is selected, and returns when the cell is deselected. This UIView is just an empty view with a background color, so it is possible that the background color is being set to clear when the table view cell is selected. None of the other elements are effected.

Does anyone have an idea what is happening here, and how to fix it?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222736/uiview-backgroundcolor-disappears-when-uitableviewcell-is-selected)