# UITableViewCell when selected, changes the foreground color also

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, selected

I have UITableView. When I select/press a UITableViewCell, not only background color but foreground color also changes. Attaching the images :

[image: Before clicking UITabelViewCell]

[image: After clicking UITabelViewCell]

Edit : I want an effect similar to this.

[image: Want an effect like this]

Comment: yourTableViewCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone

Comment: Edited my question, earlier I forgot to mention what exactly I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12838659/1276016

We need to manually change the background color of each UIView back to its normal color in setHighlighted function.